# “Application Error” and “.NET Runtime” on scheduled tasks

Tags: .net, windows

Where I work, we use many .NET application to run scheduled tasks to run various workloads necessary for business operations to continue.  We have an enterprise logging system in place, however it is configured in the program that is to be loaded so it really does not provide any information.  The only information available are normally two event logs in the event viewer.  The first is a “.NET Runtime Error” in which a stack trace is given and the description is given is “The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.”.  The second always the same regardless of the .exe, I am include the error here (I changed the path in exe name):

```
Faulting application name: Program.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5a7367c3
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.14393.1770, time stamp: 0x59bf2bcf
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000daa12
Faulting process id: 0x1b4c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d39b915704814d
Faulting application path: C:\uat\Apps\Program\JaredTest\Program.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: d07cc013-7d4a-40ff-abe3-19ece2d1e3e8
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Every time this error occurs this same event log occurs and it always has the same faulting module, exception code, and fault offset.  The only additional information I really have is that the process runs under group managed service accounts and the security might be somewhat restrictive.  The OS was rebooted and the problem persists.  I googled this issue for quite some time and I see that some people have had .NET related errors of this type in other situations but none of those threads of conversion have helped me resolve this problem.  I have some limited knowledge of windows internals, but have never really applied to such a pronounced problem like this.  This problem also seems to exist in two different server that are similarly configured.

```
Application: Program.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbHResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(System.Data.OleDb.tagDBPARAMS, System.Object ByRef)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(System.Object ByRef)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(System.Data.CommandBehavior, System.Object ByRef)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(System.Data.CommandBehavior, System.String)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(System.Data.DataSet, System.Data.DataTable[], Int32, Int32, System.String, System.Data.IDbCommand, System.Data.CommandBehavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(System.Data.DataTable[], Int32, Int32, System.Data.IDbCommand, System.Data.CommandBehavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(System.Data.DataTable)
```

This is only half of the stack trace (non company parts), however more than just this executable fails.

Comment: You need to share the code that's failing.

Comment: You need to show the connection string your using and the code that raises the oledb exception.